# csh pipe output of find command

Tags: shell, terminal, csh

I am trying to get a count of directories inside each directory of a folder.

Basically I want to go into every folder in a given directory and then run 'ls -l | wc -l'

Suppose i am in the directory that has the following structure:

```
├── sq1         
│   ├── 12      
│   ├── 123     
│   └── 1234    
├── sq2         
│   ├── 1       
│   ├── 123     
│   ├── 1234    
│   └── 345     
├── sq3
```

I want my output to be of the type:

```
sq1 3
sq2 4
sq3 0
```

I tried:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 -type d \;
```

but that lists everything . I need to count individually. How would I go about this? I am running csh.

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ls` utillity prints the number of links to a direcoty in its second colum. That number is the number of subdirectories. The two directories `.` and `..` are also counted. They are in every directory. So you have ot substract `2` from that value:

```
$ ls -ld */ | awk '$9{print $9" "$2-2}'
sq1/ 3
sq2/ 4
sq3/ 0
```

Or with the `stat` utillity:

```
$ LC_ALL=C stat -c "%F %n %h" * | awk '$1=="directory"{print $2" "$3-2}'
sq1 3
sq2 4
sq3 0
```